# adding img to div changes background-color

Tags: html, css

I had a good search through the site and I couldn't find a reference to this problem, and it's not something that's happened to me before.

Redesigning my website by updating the css. Test site is here:

http://www.thesadsongco.com/new_index.php

css is here:

http://www.thesadsongco.com/includes/styles/tssc_17.css

I'm viewing on Chrome 61.0.3163.100 and Safari 11.0 for OSX.

Except for a little bit of stuff styling hr the only element with a background definition is the body so the background image can show through all the divs with content in, and it's working fine with the text. However as soon as I add an image to any div it picks up the background colour. It's possible to see on the new_index.php in the footer, but it's much more obvious here:

http://www.thesadsongco.com/news2017.php

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change position:absolute; to position: fixed; in body::after class like this.

```
 body::after {
content: "";
background-image: url(../../media/2017/web_resources/images/worth_page_bg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 40%;
opacity: 0.5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: accept it as answer if you found it useful so that it can help others.

Comment: That's done it, thank you. I will read up to understand the solution.